# How do you control the width of the dropdown listbox in a ComboBox

Tags: winapi, mfc, atl

Is there anyway to control the width of the dropdown list of a COMBOBOX in win32?

Comment: [CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775901.aspx).

Comment: Just to add to this a little I ended up doing SendDlgItemMessage(m_hWnd,IDC_MYCOMBO,CB_SETDROPPEDWITH,width,0); Where width here was in pixels.

Comment: @MyDeveloperDay should be CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH

Answer (score 6):

I have a public method in my application class:

```
void CSoundRotaApp::UpdateComboDroppedWidth(CComboBox& rCombo)
{
    int iWidth = theApp.GetRequiredComboDroppedWidth(rCombo);
    if (iWidth > rCombo.GetDroppedWidth())
        rCombo.SetDroppedWidth(iWidth);
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
int CSoundRotaApp::GetRequiredComboDroppedWidth(CComboBox& rCombo)
{
    CString    str;
    CSize      sz;
    int        dx = 0;
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    CDC*       pDC = rCombo.GetDC();
    CFont*     pFont = rCombo.GetFont();

    // Select the listbox font, save the old font
    CFont* pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(pFont);
    // Get the text metrics for avg char width
    pDC->GetTextMetrics(&tm);

    for (int i = 0; i < rCombo.GetCount(); i++)
    {
        rCombo.GetLBText(i, str);
        sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);

        // Add the avg width to prevent clipping
        sz.cx += tm.tmAveCharWidth;

        if (sz.cx > dx)
            dx = sz.cx;
    }
    // Select the old font back into the DC
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
    rCombo.ReleaseDC(pDC);

    // Adjust the width for the vertical scroll bar and the left and right border.
    dx += ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) + 2 * ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);

    return dx;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, and instead of having to call your `UpdateComboDroppedWidth` you can make it take place in the dropdown event handler.

Comment: This code looks reasonable to me, but I have to wonder *why* you need to use it. I've never needed to customize the drop-width of a combobox. It always does the right thing out of the box, even if you're dynamically adding or removing items from it!

Comment: @CodyGray for me the issue raised due to localization etc. and the drop list was not wide enough. It was defaulting to the width of the combo and not extending the width. That was my experience.

Comment: Hmm, that is unusual. The width of the drop-down is not normally limited to the width of the combo box control itself. The only reason I can think localization might be a problem would be if you were using a font for display that did not support all of the glyphs required by that language, which was throwing off the window manager's normal width calculations. Of course, if that were true, this code doesn't seem like it would fix it, since it's using the same display font for the calculations. Couldn't say without actually seeing a test case. But I guess what works, works.

Comment: Just to clarify my question was not about how to find the length of the contents of a string, or how to call the MFC SetDroppedWidth() function, but to understand how to do this to a combobox window handle. My thanks to @IInspectable, I missed this obvious CB_XXX call and no amount of googling led me to it like you guys did here, but thanks everyone all the same. However this above code will no doubt also be useful. Thank you all.